# Исключение редиректа на https для внешнего ип-адреса

Tags: .htaccess, исключения, redirect

После перехода сайта c http на htpps, пытаюсь добавить правило запрета переадресации на https для внешнего ип, использующего http. Конфиг htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/XX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX:XXXX/connector\.php/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

При переходе по ссылке на http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/connector.php/?login=am&pass=pass&action=go&from=from происходит переадресация на https. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запретить переадресацию?

Comment: Зачем? Особенно доставляет, что судя по урлу это та единственная страница на которой точно нужен https

Comment: Затем что это внешний ресурс с которым нужно соединиться, но изменить его протокол сейчас нет возможности